# list length, inserting element

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a program in Prolog, which will insert an element into a certain position, so e.g.

```
?- ins(a, [1,2,3,4,5], 3, X).
X = [1,2,a,3,4,5].
```

I have the following code:

```
ins(X,[H|T],P,OUT) :-
   length([T3],P),
   concatenate(X,[H],T),
   ins(...).
```

The problem is that it is inserting element `X` in given index from back (I even know where the problem is -> the `length([T3],P)` which is obviously the length of the list from back not from head) . I was trying to remember how much elements did I cut off and insert `X` when "number of cut off elements" = `P`, but I can't really write that in Prolog. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% ins(Val,List,Pos,Res)

ins(Val,[H|List],Pos,[H|Res]):- Pos > 1, !, 
                                Pos1 is Pos - 1, ins(Val,List,Pos1,Res). 
ins(Val, List, 1, [Val|List]).
```

The predicate fails if Pos = 0 or Pos > length(List) + 1

Answer (score 3):

Let's state what you want here. For example you could say: "I want to split my input `List` after `Position - 1` elements so that I can insert a new element there".

A direct traduction with `append/3` (DCG would be better btw):

```
ins(Element, List, Position, Result) :-
    PrefixLength is Position - 1,
    length(Prefix, PrefixLength),
    append(Prefix, Suffix, List),
    append(Prefix, [Element], Temp),
    append(Temp, Suffix, Result).
```

Or you could say: "I want to go through the elements of my `List` `Position - 1` times without touching anything and then insert `Element` and then not touch anything again".

This time the direct traduction would be:

```
ins2(Element, List, 1, [Element|List]).
ins2(Element, [Head|Tail], Position, [Head|Result]) :-
    Position > 1,
    NewPosition is Position - 1,
    ins2(Element, Tail, NewPosition, Result).
```

you could too state that: "My input `List` is a list equal to my `Result` one except it hasn't my `Element` as `Position`th element." and realize that if you use swi-prolog, a predicate solves this instantly:

```
ins3(Element, List, Position, Result) :-
    nth1(Position, Result, Element, List).
```

Bottom line is: state what the problem is clearly and the solution should appear in simple terms.

Comment: pos>1, newPos is P -1, wuaa that's what i was looking for :) thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** To insert item `E` at position `I1` into list `Es0`, we do not need to write recursive code.

Instead, we can delegate the work (and the worries about getting it right, too!) to versatile auxiliary predicates, all of which are part of the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue). To define `ins_/4` we write:

```
ins_(E, Es0, I1, Es) :-
    maplist(any_thing, Es, [_|Es0]),
    append(Prefix, Suffix, Es0),
    length([_|Prefix], I1),
    append(Prefix, [E|Suffix], Es).

any_thing(_, _).                        % auxiliary predicate (used above)
```

Note that `maplist(any_thing, Es, [_|Es0])` is equivalent to `same_length(Es, [_|Es0])`.

Sample queries<sup>1,2,3</sup> using GNU Prolog version 1.4.4 (64-bit):

```
?- ins_(X, [a,b,c,d,e], N1, Xs).            
  N1 = 1, Xs = [X,a,b,c,d,e] 
; N1 = 2, Xs = [a,X,b,c,d,e]
; N1 = 3, Xs = [a,b,X,c,d,e]
; N1 = 4, Xs = [a,b,c,X,d,e]
; N1 = 5, Xs = [a,b,c,d,X,e]
; N1 = 6, Xs = [a,b,c,d,e,X]
; false.

?- ins_(X, [a,b,c,d,e], 3, Xs).
  Xs = [a,b,X,c,d,e]
; false.

?- ins_(X, Xs0, 3, [a,b,c,d,e]).            
  X = c, Xs0 = [a,b,d,e]
; false.
```

Let's not forget about the most general query!

```
?- ins(X, Es0, I1, Es).
  Es0 = [], I1 = 1, Es = [X]
; 
  Es0 = [A], I1 = 1, Es = [X,A]
; Es0 = [A], I1 = 2, Es = [A,X]
; 
  Es0 = [A,B], I1 = 1, Es = [X,A,B]
; Es0 = [A,B], I1 = 2, Es = [A,X,B]
; Es0 = [A,B], I1 = 3, Es = [A,B,X]
; 
  Es0 = [A,B,C], I1 = 1, Es = [X,A,B,C]
; Es0 = [A,B,C], I1 = 2, Es = [A,X,B,C]
; Es0 = [A,B,C], I1 = 3, Es = [A,B,X,C]
; Es0 = [A,B,C], I1 = 4, Es = [A,B,C,X]
; 
  Es0 = [A,B,C,D], I1 = 1, Es = [X,A,B,C,D]
; ...
```

Fair enumeration of all solutions, **OK!**

**EDIT:**
I repeated the most general query with `ins3/4` as defined 
[by @m09 in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063864/4609915) on SWI-Prolog 7.3.11 and SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 (both feature the library predicate `nth1/4`).
I was surprised to see the underlying implementations of `nth1/4` exhibit different procedural semantics (w.r.t. "fair enumeration"). See for yourself!

```
% SICStus Prolog 4.3.2                    % SWI Prolog 7.3.11
%                                         % 
?- ins3(X, Es0, I1, Es).                  %   ?- ins3(X, Es0, I1, Es).
  I1 = 1, Es0 = [], Es = [X]              %     I1 = 1, Es  = [X|Es0]
;                                         %   ; I1 = 2, Es0 = [_A|_Z], 
  I1 = 1, Es0 = [_A], Es = [X,_A]         %             Es  = [_A,X|_Z]
; I1 = 2, Es0 = [_A], Es = [_A,X]         %   ; I1 = 3, Es0 = [_A,_B|_Z],
;                                         %             Es  = [_A,_B,X|_Z] 
  I1 = 1, Es0 = [_A,_B], Es = [X,_A,_B]   %   ; I1 = 4, Es0 = [_A,_B,_C|_Z],
; I1 = 2, Es0 = [_A,_B], Es = [_A,X,_B]   %             Es  = [_A,_B,_C,X|_Z],
; I1 = 3, Es0 = [_A,_B], Es = [_A,_B,X]   %   ; I1 = 5, Es0 = [_A,_B,_C,_D|_Z],
;                                         %             Es  = [_A,_B,_C,_D,X|_Z]
...                                       %   ...
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** All sample queries shown above terminate universally.</sup>
<sup>**Footnote 2:** The answers given by the GNU Prolog toplevel have been pretty-printed a little.</sup>
<sup>**Footnote 3:** The code presented above is used *as-is*, no additional library predicates are required.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
ins(Element,List,Nth,Result) :-
    length([_|L0],Nth),
    append(L0,[_|R],List),
    append(L0,[Element|R],Result).
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: The query `?- ins_(a,[1,2,3,4,5],3,[1,2,a,3,4,5]).` fails, it should succeed.
OTOH the query `?- ins_(a,[1,2,3,4,5],3,[1,2,a,4,5]).` succeeds, it should fail. To fix the bug you need to delete exactly 4 characters:)